# Error de duplicidad al desplazarme entre pestañas con fragments

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-listview

Se me presenta el siguiente problema. Tengo un fragment con dos pestañas (A y B). En la pestaña A tengo un ListView. Esta lista muestra una serie de 5 RadioButtons agrupados en un RadioGroup. Yo lo que necesito es capturar que RadioButton está seleccionado en cada fila. Por ejemplo: Fila 1 - opción b; Fila 2 - opción a, etc...

En principio he pensado en capturar los radioButton que se vayan seleccionados con el método setOnCheckedChangeListener e ir añadiendo la posición del radiobutton al ArrayList.

Así es como lo tengo en mi adaptador:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

ArrayList<String> selectedAnswers = new ArrayList<String>();

final RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)v.findViewById(R.id.opciones_radio);

final RadioButton radio1 = (RadioButton)v.findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
        final RadioButton radio2 = (RadioButton)v.findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
        final RadioButton radio3 = (RadioButton)v.findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
        final RadioButton radio4 = (RadioButton)v.findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);
        final RadioButton radio5 = (RadioButton)v.findViewById(R.id.radioButton5);


radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, @IdRes int checkedId) {

                switch (checkedId){

                    case R.id.radioButton1 :                        
                        selectedAnswers.add("1");

                        break;

                    case  R.id.radioButton2 :                        
                        selectedAnswers.add("2");

                        break;

                    case R.id.radioButton3 :                       
                        selectedAnswers.add("3");

                        break;

                    case R.id.radioButton4 :                        
                        selectedAnswers.add("4");

                        break;

                    case R.id.radioButton5 :                        
                        selectedAnswers.add("5");

                        break;
                }

                Log.e("RESPUESTA: ", String.valueOf(selectedAnswers));

            }
        });

}
```

Pero esto no funciona bien.
El problema principal (entre otros) es que si selecciono algún radioButton y me muevo entre pestañas, por ejemplo de la pestaña A a la pestaña B, el Arraylist se duplica.

Por ejemplo, el código anterior devuelve esto:

> E/RESPUESTA:: [1, 2, 5, 1]

Pero si ahora me muevo de la pestaña A a la pestaña B y regreso. Me duplica dos veces el arrayList:

> E/RESPUESTA:: [1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 5, 1]

En lugar de con setOnCheckedChangeListener lo he intentado con setOnClickListener, pero tampoco funciona bien.

¿Alguna pista sobre esta asunto? Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta vaciar el arreglo dentro del `onCheckedChanged`.

```
selectedAnswers.clear();
```

Tuve el mismo problema que tu con un listview dentro de un fragment y al desplazarme me duplicaba los resultados, esto lo provoca al estar dentro del fragment, una de sus funciones es mantener el contenido y tus radioButtons inicialmente supongo están en false por lo que el listener se activa de nuevo y tienes método de agregar `selectedAnswers.add("")` por lo que vuelve a imprimir mas resultados.Si limpias tu arreglo antes del switch al regresar este imprimirá solo una vez lo que esta en la lista.

Comment: Gracias Erick. Efectivamente, el método clear() era necesario para evitar las duplicidades al moverse entre diferentes pestañas.

Answer (score 0):

al final conseguí solucionarlo. Para ello simplemente tuve que sustituir el método .add por el método .set y situando los diferentes radioButtons en true o false, quedando el código de esta manera:

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, @IdRes int checkedId) {

                switch (checkedId){

                    case R.id.radioButton1 :
                        selectedAnswers.set(position, "1");
                        radio1.setChecked(true);
                        radio2.setChecked(false);
                        radio3.setChecked(false);
                        radio4.setChecked(false);
                        radio5.setChecked(false);
                        break;

                    case  R.id.radioButton2 :
                        selectedAnswers.set(position, "2");
                        radio1.setChecked(false);
                        radio2.setChecked(true);
                        radio3.setChecked(false);
                        radio4.setChecked(false);
                        radio5.setChecked(false);
                        break;

                    case R.id.radioButton3 :
                        selectedAnswers.set(position, "3");
                        radio1.setChecked(false);
                        radio2.setChecked(false);
                        radio3.setChecked(true);
                        radio4.setChecked(false);
                        radio5.setChecked(false);
                        break;

                    case R.id.radioButton4 :
                        selectedAnswers.set(position, "4");
                        radio1.setChecked(false);
                        radio2.setChecked(false);
                        radio3.setChecked(false);
                        radio4.setChecked(true);
                        radio5.setChecked(false);
                        break;

                    case R.id.radioButton5 :
                        selectedAnswers.set(position, "5");
                        radio1.setChecked(false);
                        radio2.setChecked(false);
                        radio3.setChecked(false);
                        radio4.setChecked(false);
                        radio5.setChecked(true);
                        break;
                }
```

También limpiando el array al iniciar el adaptador con `selectedAnswers.clear();` de forma que no se dupliquen los registros al cambiar de ventana y regresar.

Dejo aquí la respuesta por si le sirve a alguien. Saludos.